# Routing in BackboneJs, involving Jquery Mobile and Asp.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm trying to use backbonejs as my router, routing does not seems to work for subpath nor splat. I'm using MVC 4 together with Jquery mobile for this project and hopes it does not cause conflict in the routing.

The result of testing are below:

`http://localhost` gives me "Routed to home" in console. (correct)

`http://localhost/#contacts` gives me "Routed to contacts list" in console. (correct)

`http://localhost/#contacts?1` stills gives me "Routed to contacts list" in console. (wrong)

`http://localhost/#contacts/view/1` redirects me to `http://localhost/contacts/view/1` and gives me a 404 error since I do not have such page. (wrong)

I have tried using splats, and I got the exact same problem as my 4th example. Please guide me on what I might be doing wrong.

Here's my code sample.

app.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'backbone',
  'router',
], function ($, Backbone, Router) {
    var initialize = function () {
        $(document).on("mobileinit",
        // Set up the "mobileinit" handler before requiring jQuery Mobile's module
            function () {

                $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false
                $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false
                $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false
                $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false

                $('div[data-role="page"]').live('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
                    $(event.currentTarget).remove();
                })
            });

        require(["jquerymobile"], function () {
            // Instantiates a new Backbone.js Mobile Router
            this.router = new Router();
        });
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

router.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'jquerymobile',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  '../../scripts/backbone/views/home/HomeView',
  '../../scripts/backbone/views/footer/FooterView',
], function ($, Mobile, _, Backbone, HomeView, FooterView) {

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            var homeView = new HomeView();
            homeView.render();

            var footerView = new FooterView();
            footerView.render();
            Backbone.history.start({ pushState: false  });
        },
        routes: {

            'contacts': 'contactList',
            'contacts?:id': 'contactsDetail',
            'contacts/view/:id': 'contactsDetail',

            //'*actions': 'home',
            '': 'home'
        },
        // Home method
        home: function () {
            console.log("Routed to home");
        },
        contactList: function () {
            console.log("Routed to contacts list");
        },
        contactsDetail: function (id) {
            console.log("Routed to contacts detail");
        }
    });

    return AppRouter;
});
```